# xCode external build No such file or directory

Tags: xcode

I have added a new target with external build in xCode 4.3.2 which is suposed to run a shell script. The script is in a folder Scripts/update.sh in the project.
My external build tool configuration are:

```
Build Tool /bin/bash
Arguments ../Scripts/update.sh
```

But when i run i get:

```
 /bin/bash: ../Scripts/update.sh: No such file or directory
```

How do i refer the file correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html), it looks like you probably want refer to `update.sh` as:

```
${SRCROOT}/Scripts/update.sh
```